# How to implement mutually coupled inductor in SimuLink

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, simulation, matlab, simulink

I want to make a mutually coupled boost converter but I could not find any mutually coupled inductor block in MATLAB SimuLink. Please help, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Usually sims have a component called K and this can be set to name the inductors to be coupled and the coupling factor. Try looking for K or something that might be similar. I've never used SimuLink but I cannot imagine that something radically different to most other conventional sims is going to implemented.

Comment: Is sims and simuLink different?

Comment: Sims is a generic term for a simulator of which there are dozens and dozens. Open your eyes lol.

Answer (score 0):

**For others than Simulink users**: It's not a circuit analyzer, but calculates functions that are defined with math block diagrams. Actually it's a graphical user interface for inputting simulation equations and performing the simulation. There's in the background MATLAB.

[What is Simulink](https://se.mathworks.com/products/simulink.html)

**EDIT** the explanation above is in 2017 a false belief. Simulink has also a circuit analyzer as one of the numerous available options. It's shown in another answer. I leave this answer as an example of how much one can waste energy by building on obsolete assumptions.

**Back to the question:**

I believe that you do not want to use numerical differentation, but integrators to have a hope for convergence.

To simulate single ideal inductor you need only one integrator. Its gain factor is 1/L. The input variable is the voltge and the output is the current of the inductor.

Mutual inductance needs 2 integrators. The block diagram can be derived from this basic relation:

[image]

Those equations are not valid for numerical simulation as is, because they have derivatives (=multiplied by s). If one simply moves say I1 to the left side and all else to the right side, he has

I1 = U1/(s * L1) - (M/L1) * I2

I2 = U2/(s * L2) - (M/L2) * I1

No derivatives - this seems at first to be valid! But it has an algebraic loop. Every sample period needs iterating an algebraic equation. Very sophisticated simulation can do it, but not any streamlined crunching, so let's forget it.

If ve solve properly I1 and I2 from the basic relation, we get usable equations:

[image]

Currents I1 and I2 are integrated from  linear sums of U1 and U2.

I tried this. I tried a 50Hz 315V peak mains separating transformer with 100 ohm resistive load (U2 = -100 * I2) and got the right results. I used L1 = L2 = 10 henrys (=very low) and the coupling coefficient k = 0,95

NOTE: This also can diverge if you have low losses in the simulated circuit or very high mutual coupling coefficient k. Term A grows easily very high  if k is near 1.

Unfortunately I do not have MATLAB & Simulink at home, so I used low cost alternatives (only trapezoidal integrator, no ability to solve algebraic loops). But that does not change the basic math. Here's a screenshot of my test:

[image]

EDIT: I believed that the questioner copies my block diagram only leaving off  the gain block -100 (=the load and it's connection) and makes a compound block that has inputs for L1, L2, k, U1 and U2. Its outputs were I1 and I2.

Note: I2 is in my math reversed when compared to the usual direction in output side. That's why 100 Ohm is represented as -100.

Comment: actually, simulink can simulate circuits

Comment: @JonRB Caramba! If it really understands circuit diagrams as ordinary electric circuit analyzers, I need to update my beliefs. And delete my obsolete answer. Can you add a circuit diagram simulation screenshot as a final nail?

Comment: should be able to, I use simulink daily. Let me knock something up

Comment: @JonRB a 320V  peak amplitude, 50Hz sinusoidal voltage source is connected through a 1:1 transformer to a 100 Ohm resistance. Transformer has identical primary and secondary, both 10H inductance, coupling coefficient=0,95, no resistance in wires. Simulate 0,2 seconds and show the currents in transformer's input and output. I want to see the page how this is inputted as circuit.

Comment: done  included in my reply.  I used a dashboard more for visuals as I would normally used scopes or sparklines

Answer (score 0):

There are three mutual inductance blocks in Matlab:Simulink. All require the Simscape module & the other two require additional modules

[image]

Example simulation

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Here's your circuit, with working simulation with coupling coefficient K=0.95:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fly0RU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Click to open it in CircuitLab and run the simulation to see the primary and secondary currents over the first 0.2 seconds of operation, as you requested!

In CircuitLab this is done using a parameter where the name is "K L1 L2", indicating the coupling coefficient between an inductor named "L1" and an inductor named "L2", and the value in this case is 0.95 as you specified in your problem statement. In other software, it's probably similar.

Comment: that is circuitlab, not simulink

Comment: Thanks, but this answer is unnecessary. The chat was about "can or cannot modern version of Simulink parse and analyze circuit diagrams". I have not seen it and @JonRB proved that my knowhow is dontknowhow. Of course I asked something that I can easily check. Simulink of today also can have a circuit analyzer among its zillion other installed and installable capablities.

Comment: @actually this answer is useful, because it shows that Simulink gets the same result.